# WCF AfterReceiveRequest not firing

Tags: wcf

I am using a self hosted WCF service and I am getting a little strange behavior from my service:
I use an Implementation of IDispatchMessageInspector to keep track of the requests/responses processed by my service.

When I add my service by using "Add service reference dialog" everything works fine. AfterReceivedRequest and BeforeSendReply is fired.

When I create the binding/endpoint using code only the service works fine, but AfterReceivedRequest and BeforeSendReply is not fired.

I'd be very happy if someone could point me in the right direction.

Marco.

Edit: here is the Code of the client creation:

```
Public Shared Function Do_RM(ByVal RMParameter As roClsRMParameter) As ROD.RM.Services.RoClsRMResult

    Dim StartAdresse As String
    Dim myBinding As BasicHttpBinding
    Dim oRes As ROD.RM.Services.RoClsRMResult = Nothing

    myBinding = Create_Binding()
    myBinding.OpenTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, TimeOutInSekunden)
    myBinding.SendTimeout = New TimeSpan(0, 0, TimeOutInSekunden)
    StartAdresse = "http://MyServer:8731/BASIC"
    Dim Address = New EndpointAddress(StartAdresse)

    Dim Client = New ROD.RM.Services.RODIS_QS_RMClient(myBinding, Address)
    Client.Endpoint.Contract = Create_ContractDescription()

    Client.Open()
    oRes = Client.DoRM(RMParameter.A_BEL,
                       RMParameter.A_POS,
                       RMParameter.AVO,
                       RMParameter.Qualitaet,
                       RMParameter.Fehlernummer,
                       RMParameter.Anlage,
                       RMParameter.ChargenNr,
                       RMParameter.EinzelRueckmeldung,
                       RMParameter.NurTest,
                       RMParameter.Standort)
    Client.Close()
    Return oRes
End Function

Private Shared Function Create_ContractDescription() As ContractDescription

    Dim oContract As ContractDescription
    oContract = ContractDescription.GetContract(GetType(ROD.RM.Services.IRODIS_QS_RM), GetType(ROD.RM.Services.RODIS_QS_RMClient))
    Return oContract
End Function

Private Shared Function Create_Binding() As BasicHttpBinding

    Dim oHttpBinding As BasicHttpBinding = New BasicHttpBinding()

    oHttpBinding.Name = "BasicHttpBinding_IRODIS_QS_RM"
    oHttpBinding.CloseTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    oHttpBinding.OpenTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    oHttpBinding.ReceiveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10)
    oHttpBinding.SendTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)
    oHttpBinding.BypassProxyOnLocal = False
    oHttpBinding.HostNameComparisonMode = HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard
    oHttpBinding.MaxBufferPoolSize = 524288
    oHttpBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 65536
    oHttpBinding.MessageEncoding = WSMessageEncoding.Text
    oHttpBinding.TextEncoding = Encoding.UTF8
    oHttpBinding.UseDefaultWebProxy = True
    oHttpBinding.AllowCookies = False

    oHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxDepth = 32
    oHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 16384
    oHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 8192
    oHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxBytesPerRead = 4096
    oHttpBinding.ReaderQuotas.MaxNameTableCharCount = 16384

    Return oHttpBinding
End Function
```

Here are the parts for the Inspector of the Service:

```
Imports System.ServiceModel.Description

Public Class roClsRMLogBehavior
    Implements IEndpointBehavior

    Public Sub ApplyDispatchBehavior(ByVal endpoint As _
               System.ServiceModel.Description.ServiceEndpoint, ByVal _
               endpointDispatcher As _
               System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.EndpointDispatcher) _
        Implements System.ServiceModel.Description.IEndpointBehavior.ApplyDispatchBehavior

        Dim oInspector As roClsRMLog
        oInspector = New roClsRMLog
        endpointDispatcher.DispatchRuntime.MessageInspectors.Add(oInspector)
End Sub
```

End Class

In the app.Config:

```
<extensions>
  <behaviorExtensions>
    <add name="roClsRMLogBehavior" type="RODIS_QS_BUCHEN_SERVICE.roclsRMLogBehaviorExtensionElement, RODIS_QS_BUCHEN_SERVICE, Version=1.1.3.1,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null"/>
  </behaviorExtensions>  
</extensions>
```

Comment: Show the code where you create the client connection. Do you apply the inspector to a behavior of your endpoint?

Comment: since your code works using add service reference dialog, i presume your inspector is added to the dispatch run time, as CodeCaster highlighted, it could be that you have forgotten to add the behavior to service end points.. following post has a nice example  - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2011/04/19/wcf-extensibility-message-inspectors.aspx

Comment: I need to add the Inspector on the Client-side as well?

Comment: When you say you have created Binding/Endpoints using code only.. are you referring to the client? If you are creating endpoints through code at the server, you need to add behavior to the service endpoint.. something like this endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new roClsRMLogBehavior());

Comment: Sorry I was unprecise: The client is created by code.

Comment: how are you adding the behavior extension "roClsRMLogBehavior" to your service?

Comment: I found the solution to my problem: I was plain simple stupid :(

I wasn't carefull enough in going through my Service code and ended up checking the wrong inspector methods..
All was working all the time I just passed a variable without a value in one case that caused an exception that prevented the logging from happening.

I am very sorry and also very thankfull for your answers/comments.

Next time I will make sure to pinpoint where exactly the error is bevore asking for help.

Marco.